# Is (was) the Crystalline Entity unique?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Before its destruction, was the Crystalline Entity one of a kind? Or is there information leading one to believe that various Entities were in existence at some point?

Answer (score 13):

Within the TV canon, there was only one Crystalline Entity (e.g. the one seen in the episodes [Datalore](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Datalore_(episode)) and [Silicon Avatar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Silicon_Avatar_(episode))). There are several lines in the second episode which confirm that it's the same creature as in the first:

> **DATA:** *Trace elements confirm that it was the **same entity** which destroyed the colony on Omicron Theta.*

The crew also make it pretty clear that it's unlike anything the Federation has encountered before.

> **[DATA](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/114.txt) :**... *confirmed by Lore's report to be an **unknown kind of creature**, capable of stripping all life from an entire world...*

and

> **GEORDI :** *It's like a snowflake crystal, sir. But much more complex... **I haven't the slightest idea what it is, sir**.*

---

Moving further down the canon scale, we see *numerous* crystalline entities in the Trek novel [Orion's Hounds](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Orion%27s_Hounds).

> Troi turned to Oderi, who was back on her feet and consulting the
>   status-display band she wore about her wrist. “What is it? What’s
>   going on.”
>
> “The station is under attack by branchers.”
>
> “Branchers?”
>
> “A very, very deadly form of starbeast. Huge living crystals. They
>   fire beams that disintegrate living matter and absorb its bio-energy.
>   They—”
>
> “Oh, my God. Can you show me an image?”
>
> Oderi nodded and tweaked her status band to project a small hologram
>   of the scene outside the station. Deanna gasped at the sight of the
>   familiar, ramified blue forms closing in on their position. They were
>   the same kind of Crystalline Entity that had destroyed Data’s
>   homeworld decades ago.
>
> **And there were three of them.**

There's also a much bigger specimen seen in the Star Trek Online episode "[The Crystalline Catastrophe](http://web.archive.org/web/20130518044323/http://sto.perfectworld.com/news/?p=859041)". It takes roughly ten sovereign-class vessels to kill it.

[image]